# Spring Data support for Google Big Query

Tags: spring-data, google-bigquery

Is anyone aware if support for google big query is in the backlog for Spring Data?

Also interested in any existing attempts to create a Spring Data module for Big Query.

Finally I was curious what attempting to build such a module and donate it to the Spring Community would entail.

Comment: It's a good thought, but not an appropriate question for SO. You could try asking here instead: https://issuetracker.google.com

Comment: The [Spring Data project page](http://projects.spring.io/spring-data/) lists the modules officially and unofficially supported by the project. Google BigQuery is not listed there so it is not one of the supported technologies as yet. That said, BigQuery supports the SQL-92 standard and [Google provides JDBC drivers for BigQuery](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/partners/simba-drivers/) so it should be theoretically possible to use BigQuery with Spring Data JPA.

Comment: If you still want to implement your own Spring Data module, you can use one of the existing modules as a starting point. Typically you would want to have an interface that defines the contract for the data store (see `JdbcOperations` or `MongoOperations`) and a `Template` class that provides an implementation of the contract (see `JdbcTemplate` or `MongoTemplate`) that provide the store-specific functionality. Then, a `Repository` interface and its implementation that utilizes the `Template` class will provide the Spring Data layer on top of the store-specific layer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. There is no Spring Data Google BigQuery module. If you can use JPA as @manish suggests, you can use Spring Data JPA
2. In order to create your own module, I suggest you start [with the developer guide in the wiki](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-commons/wiki/Developer-guide). It's not complete, but it should give you a start. Also looking at existing modules helps a lot. I'd recommend the MongoDB and Key Value modules.

If you have more specific questions about building a spring data module, SO is your friend.